# Calculations on a date column formatted as text

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, sumifs

I need to calculate a sum in one column based on a date range in another.

```
=SUMIFS(Data!$A:$A,Data!$B:$B,">4/1/2014")
```

The caveat is that the date column is being loaded as text by someone else (cannot control this).  And worse, I cannot create another column that does something like

```
=DATEVALUE($A1)
```

because I can't expect this person to fill that formula down every time new data is added.

My only thought is to apply a DATEVALUE to the whole column, possibly as an array formula or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible by using the more clunky but extremely versatile `SUMPRODUCT` function:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((DATEVALUE(Data!$B:$B)>DATE(2014;1;4))*Data!$A:$A)
```

What it does is determine an array of all cells where `DATEVALUE() > DATE(...)` and then multiply this array of TRUE/FALSE items with your data.

Comment: Seems like DATEVALUE() does not play nice within SUMPRODUCT.  I tried 
`=SUMPRODUCT(--(DATEVALUE($B:$B)>DATE(2014,1,4)),$A:$A)`
and received a #VALUE! error while 
`=SUMPRODUCT(--(($B:$B)>DATE(2014,5,7)),$A:$A)` works just fine.  Thoughts?

Comment: Are all of your entries in the column dates, or is there a column header or similar which cannot be converted to a date?

Comment: Okay I think it has to do with the empty cells in that column.
Works: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(DATEVALUE($B1:$B11)>DATE(2014,5,7)),$A1:$A11)`
Doesn't work: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(DATEVALUE($B:$B)>DATE(2014,5,7)),$A:$A)`

Comment: That sounds like the explanation.

Comment: Then the easiest way is probably using a dynamic named range:
`=SUMPRODUCT(--(DATEVALUE(rng_ColumnB)>DATE(2014,5,7)),rng_ColumnA)`
where rng_ColumnB is `=OFFSET($B$1,,,COUNTA($B:$B))`

There's probably a [better] way that would test for spaces but I can't seem to get IFERROR() or IF() to work within the SUMPRODUCT().