# Nested function in excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am trying to get the count of cells in a column containing dates having future date.
The column values are in string format.

I have figured out the formula as :

```
=COUNTIF(G19:G31,">" & TODAY())
```

This function works when the column values are in date format. But its failing if the cell format is in string format.

I have figured out the formula to convert a cell string value to date :

```
=DATEVALUE(G19)
```

Here are my queries:
1) How to apply DATEVALUE on a range , in this case from G19:G31?
2) How to combine these two formulas in to one single formula?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23296538/calculations-on-a-date-column-formatted-as-text/23568188

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

=SUMPRODUCT(--((G19:G31+0)>TODAY()))

COUNTIF will not accept anything other than a range as its first argument so you can't use functions there.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This approach is working fine in case all the cells G19:G31 has data but giving Value error in case any of the cells is empty. Can we handle that?

Comment: Have you tried using an Iferror formula around what was provided above?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to write `=SUM(IF(DATEVALUE(G19:G31) > TODAY(), 1, 0))`

**But** this will be an **array** formula: you need to press Ctrl + Shift + Return once you've done editing, rather than just Return.